# Functions becoming undefined when evaluated

Tags: function-construction

I'm so confused I don't even know how to phrase my Question title.

My function `nextCol` works until I use `colLength`, then `nextCol` doesn't work anymore.

```
$RecursionLimit = Infinity;
nextCol[m_, n_] := 
   Module[{}, 
   t = m;
   Do[While[Mod[t, Prime[j]] == 0, t = t/Prime[j]], {j, 1, n - 1}];
   Return[If[t == 1, 1, t*Prime[n] + 1]]];
colLength[m_, n_] := 
   Module[{}, 
     Return[If[m == 1, 1, 1 + colLength[nextCol[m, n], n]]]];

nextCol[10001, 5]
(* 110012 *)

colLength[10001, 5]
(* DING! from my laptop but no error or warning message *)

nextCol[10001, 5]
(* nextCol[10001, 5]  *)
```

It's like `nextCol` somehow made *Mathematica* forget the definition of `nextCol`.

And this problem doesn't happen for most inputs pairs.

Is this an *Mathematica* bug or did I do something wrong?

Comment: The ding you hear is your kernel crashing, probably because you removed the recursion limit and exhausted the stack space. Once the kernel crashes, it forgets any definitions you made.

Comment: @MarcoB  Yeah, that was the problem.  Thanks.  If you want to put this as an Answer, I will Accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ding you hear is your kernel crashing, probably because you removed the recursion limit and exhausted the stack space. Once the kernel crashes, it forgets any definitions you made.